# select control manipulation not working

Tags: jquery

I am using the jquery live function to create multiple widgets on a page using ...

```
$('#mybutton').live('click', function(){
var first = $('#win-doors-pvc fieldset:first').html();   
$(first).find('select option:selected').attr('selected',false);   
$('#win-doors-pvc').append('<fieldset>'+first+'</fieldset>');
});
```

The code above successfully re-creates the content within a fieldset.

The content with var first contains a select control.
I would like to manipulate that select by using

```
$(first).find('select option:selected').attr('selected',false);
```

to de-select what has been selected.

Why does it not work ?

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/4MEbU/:

```
$('#mybutton').live('click', function(){
var first = $('#win-doors-pvc fieldset:first');   
first.find('select option:selected').attr('selected',false);   
$('#win-doors-pvc').append('<fieldset>'+first.html()+'</fieldset>');
});
```

Your code doesn't work because you do

```
var first = $('#win-doors-pvc fieldset:first').html();
```

then `first` is a string containing html, so `$(first)` gives an empty object.

Instead of this, `first` should be a reference to the element (not its html code):

```
var first = $('#win-doors-pvc fieldset:first');
```

so `first.find('select option:selected').attr('selected',false);` works well.

When you want its html code, just use `first.html()`

```
$('#win-doors-pvc').append('<fieldset>'+first.html()+'</fieldset>')
```

**Edit**:

If you want the new element to have the same `option` selected than the first `select`, you can move itself:

```
$('#mybutton').live('click', function(){
    var first = $('#win-doors-pvc fieldset:first');
    $('#win-doors-pvc').append(first);
    $('#win-doors-pvc').prepend(first.clone(true,true));
});
​
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/4MEbU/3/

Comment: The problem though is that the copied fieldset:first (containing the select control) also now has its select control set to false as a result of first.find('select option:selected').attr('selected',false);